# Using templates for c++

Tags: c++, templates, object

I tried to use templates on the following code but i have a problem with the first line of the main function!

```
{
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  template <class T>
  struct node
  {
        T inf;
         node<T> * next;
 };
 template <class S>
 class String
{
     private :
            int Slength;
          node<S> * SS;
   public :
         void get_String()
         {
              SS = new node<S>;
              SS -> next = NULL;
              node<S> * now = SS; 
              char input;
              while(input = getchar())
              {
                          if((input =='\n') || (input == ' ') || (input == '\t'))
                                    break;
                          now -> inf = input;
                          now -> next = new node<S>;
                          now = now -> next;
                          now -> next = NULL;
                          ++Slength;
              }
         }
         void show()
         {
              node<S> * now = SS;
              while(now -> next != NULL)
              {
                        cout << now -> inf ;
                        now = now -> next;
              }
              cout << endl;
         }
 };
 int main()
 {
 String a;
 a.get_String();
 a.show();
 cout << char(0) << " " << int(' ') << " " <<endl;  
 system("pause");
 return 0; 
 }
```

I have the problem solved with adding

```
<char>
```

after that!
Is there any other good and efficient way.
And do you know any dependable and readable reference for templates?

Comment: Why is there a `{` at the beginning of the code?

Comment: When you instantiate a class template, you need to supply an argument list. If you had `template <class T=char> class String ...`, you'd be able to use `String<> a;`, but even with defaults for all the template arguments, you need to include the angle brackets. BTW, a string as a linked list of characters is going to be *horrendously* inefficient (figure at least 4 bytes of pointers for every byte of actual data). Since you're allocating nodes dynamically, it's probably even worse than that -- typically a minimum of 16 or 32 bytes per node.

Comment: @talnicolas: Hmm...you see that sometimes at the beginning of [cint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CINT) scripts that are intended to be invoked interactively, but in that case you wouldn't need to `#include` a standard header like `iostream`.

Answer (score 4):

Since `String` is a template class, it should be:

```
String<char> a;
```